# Module that adds a script to the header

Tags: 7, features

How can I allow my module (created with Features) to add a new script to the head?

The script should be in the correspoinding module directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a script using `drupal_add_js` and to have it added on every page, you can call it in `hook_init`.

Module directory path can be resolved by `drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name')`

```
module_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name')."/js/myscript.js");
}
```